# Move divs on the Y axis at different times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have each sentence slide up but at different times. Right now they all slide up at the same time. I want the first sentence to slide up and then maybe `0.1s` later, the second sentence slides up and so on. Here's my javascript. I'm trying to do this with javascript only and no additional css.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="sentences">The first sentence</div>

    <div class="sentences">The second sentence</div>

    <div class="sentences">The third sentence</div>

</div>



function moveSentences() {

    $('.sentences').css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -20)');

} 

moveSentences();
```

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brewpixels/ku4puujz/)

Comment: Have you tried using CSS3 transition-delay property? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp You can give different delay to each

Comment: Two issues.  One is that you're applying the transform on all "sentences" element at once.  Two is that you're "sentences" class has no delay attribute.   You can try applying "transition-timing-function: ease-in;" to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you can loop through the elements and work with a delay:

```
$('.sentences').each(function(i, item) {
    $(this)
        .delay(100 * i)
        .queue(function() {
            $(this).css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -20)').dequeue();
        });
});
```

Comment: How do I make the animation play every 5 seconds? I want the function to run every 5 seconds, looping the animation. I added setinterval(moveSentences, 5000); to my code but it still only plays once.

Comment: Instead of setting the css property `transform` you could use `jQuery.animate` to somehow decrease y each time. Would that be your original goal?

Comment: Yes because I want the divs to keep moving up on the y axis

Answer (score 0):

```
 var i = 0;
    var length = $('.sentences').length;
    var x = -20;
    function moveSentences() {
        alert('hi');
        $('.sentences').eq(i).css('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0,' + x + ')')
        x = x - 20;
        i++;
    }

   var intrval= setInterval(function () {

            moveSentences()
            if (i >= length) {
                clearInterval(intrval);
            }
        }, 1000)
```